# How to grep 7 digits of numbers and sort them in uniqe

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I have a file like

```
Gfh   To:9865412342
Gfds  To:9865416787
Hgf   To:9865415447
```

Then i want one of them just because the first 6 digits in 3 of them are the same 
Like :Gfh To:9865412342

I tried `grep 'to:98[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]’ | sort -u` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
grep -o '^[[:alnum:]]\+\s\+[Tt]o:98[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' file | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the upper and lower case are not the point,the point is that idont konw how to consider the first 7 digits in the numbers to have just a unique number

Comment: Check edited post, wou will see the numbers of similar first 6 digits like this

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful but is there a way to print Gfh in output too?

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: Thanks aloootttttt pal, it worked by some changes like grep -o ‘^sth that don’t chenge [[:alpha:]]\+ ‘to:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]’’ file | sort -n | uniq -c